# Slack replace message with ephemeral response_type to in_channel

Tags: node.js, integration, slack

I'm trying to integrate some interactive actions to slack app.
one of steps - give user ability to select one or several options, which should be visible just for him.

It works good with `response_type=ephemeral`
but in the end everyone have to see message, and replace `response_type` to `in_channel` doesn't give any result

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you're asking? I've read your question twice now and believe your problem is that you want the option only shown to one user, but he message itself should be visible to a channel – is that correct? If so, consider updating your question's title and message to make that clearer. People are more likely to answer it then.

Comment: using `response_type` with `in_channel` usually works great, so the problem is most likely in your code. Which you unfortunately did not post. Please add it to your question.

Comment: Having the same issue than OP. Basically, if you publish a message as ephemeral and use the action button to return a response, the original message is updated with that response. However, setting  the response_type to In_channel in the action button response does nothing. Message get updated but still shows "only visible to you". I think you might need to do a chat.delete then post a new message with in_channel as response type.